# .NET Core 1.0 Deployment issue with dotnet-razor-tooling.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to deploy a recently upgraded .NET Core 1.0 solution to IIS with a few issues that I can't seem to find any information on. The site runs in IIS Express without issue. It's taken me a few hours to even get to the root of the issue by running the site through command prompt and it seems an assembly "dotnet-razor-tooling.dll" cannot be found.

I've checked the locations it tries to find it and it's simply not present. Searching around the web for that DLL brings up nothing (not a good sign!). Can anyone point me in the direction of any potential fixes here?

[image]

I've also installed ASP.NET Core Module on the box and made sure my web.config/appsettings.json are being transformed post-publish. All seems to be fine on that part.

Comment: I get a couple results with ["dotnet-razor-tooling.dll"](https://www.google.be/#q=%22dotnet-razor-tooling.dll%22). Do you have the latest tooling installed?

Comment: Very odd, in the first URL I see he's running C:\Users\nimullen\.nuget\packages\dotnet-razor-tooling\

In the same folder structure I don't have this folder and I've got the latest version of .NET Core installed on my box! The plot thickens.

Comment: Another weird thing is that I'm referencing: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools/1.0.0-preview2-final in my JSON. No mention anywhere is dotnet-razor-tooling.

Comment: That package does contain the dll you're looking for, maybe it's not copied to the output directory then?

Comment: Yep, that's the thing, I can't find that DLL anywhere. Not on my PC (which runs the site via IIS), or on the box. It's like it's a phantom DLL and no idea why it's being referenced.

Comment: Try reinstalling that package then. If you go to the page, at the left there's a *Download* link. You can open the file with a ZIP tool like 7-Zip: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq4Wc.png

Comment: Thank you, but that seems to have opened up a whole bag of worms and now more assemblies aren't being found, such as System.Composition.AttributedModel.dll. I can't possibly think of anything else I've missed installing.

Comment: Especially when I don't have that DLL locally anywhere! Sigh...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem when did local publishing of my asp.net core application. I've solved it by installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor package and updating all packages included prerelease. 
I hope that helps you.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final (prerelease) works for me. Seems to be a bug in preview1.