# ASP.NET Core on Azure: Can not find assembly file dotnet-razor-tooling.exe

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core

I cannot find the problem within my ASP.NET Core application.
After deployment on azure it says: Internal server error. 
Exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Can not find assembly file dotnet-razor-tooling.exe at 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\refs,D:\home\site\wwwroot\'
```

project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Server": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "NLog": "4.3.7",
    "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rtm-alpha4",
    "NLog.Interface": "3.2.1",
    "PostSharp": "4.3.15"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "JECodingTest.Business": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Tried to [update Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147509/net-core-1-0-deployment-issue-with-dotnet-razor-tooling-dll), but id did not help me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You mentioned trying to update Razor, but your `project.json` still references `1.0.0-preview1-final`. The latest version is `preview2`. Have you tried that version?

Comment: Thanks Nate! I had to tap "include pre-release" checkbox, so that update appeared. updating to v1.0.0-preview2-final - fixed the trouble!

Comment: Great! I'll create an answer in case anyone else runs into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error can occur if you're using an older version of the Razor tooling packages. In your `project.json`, you have:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
},
```

The [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools) at the time of writing is `1.0.0-preview2-final`. You can update the packages by editing the `project.json` file directly, or by using the NuGet Package Manager GUI (make sure to select Include Prerelease).

Make sure that **both** the package reference in the `dependencies` section and the reference in the `tools` section get updated.